# Power shell Copy/move daily multiple .txt/.cvs files from network drive to network drive, local to network drive or vice versa

Tags: windows, powershell

Condition

- network drive (origin-f: destination O:)
- file is above 50mb.
  -only mentioned specific words as new file is genrated everyday with $currentdate in the filename  Eg: "xxxx202206141010"

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\*" -Include *AppliedInnovations*.txt | 
    where { $_.Length -gt 40mb}
        Copy-Item -Destination "O:\Applied Innovations Database\" -force**
```

**Result**

```
OUTPUT
Directory: F:\
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         6/14/2022  10:50 AM       57798073 AppliedInnovations-202206141010.txt

cmdlet Copy-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]:
```

The outcome is to transfer this file .txt FROM *F: to O:* and these are network drive, was given an error for UNC path so used regular path.

ANY HELP/SUGGESTIONS please thank you

Comment: PS C:\Users\dataentry3>
>> Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\*" -Include *AppliedInnovations*.txt |
>>         where { $_.Length -gt 40mb}
>>         Copy-Item -Destination "O:\Applied Innovations Database\" -force


    Directory: F:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
---a----         6/14/2022  10:50 AM       57798073 AppliedInnovations-202206141010.txt

cmdlet Copy-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]:

Comment: You're missing a pipe. Any reason you're filtering for a single file in the same directory?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yes, i have 2 files it in with same file name so have to filter it with file Size.

Comment: @mklement0 edited thank you. hope my question is understandable now.

Comment: That's better, thanks. As Abraham has already noted, you're missing a `|` before the `Copy-Item` call, which makes the latter a stand-alone statement, which - due to lack of input - prompts for the required input path. Simply replace `where { $_.Length -gt 40mb}` with `where { $_.Length -gt 40mb} |`

Comment: @mklement0 you were absolutely correct, i was just gonna write it now. And now i understood what Abraham was asking. But yes, very much appreiciated, was a silly mistake. It worked. This was a prototype gonna work on the real problem now (transfer all .csv files from x folder to y and create a task scheduler for that.

Comment: Although, I did use "|" in one of the trial ,dint work then but works now "silly syntax error i guess Thanks to both of you. Although I was afraid myt have to use robocopy, wonder when does that come in picture since I have never used it.